# Is there an alternative to FileOutputStream type , which does not create a file?

Tags: java, android

To process some images in my android application I currently use code like this:

```
   FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(imgpath);
   [..DO SOME STUFF..]
   Bitmap data = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bFile, 0, bFile.length, options);
   data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOuputStream);
   [..DO SOME STUFF..]              
   File file = new File(imgpath);   
   FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
   imageInFile.read(imageData);
   [..DO SOME STUFF..]
   file.delete();
   //NOTE: The code is all in the same method
```

the problem is that passing my image  from one part of the code to another using this method creates a temporary file.

I was looking for a way to read / write the file data using a memory variable, something like "generic stream" in which store data in order to replace use of "FileInputStream " and "FileOutputStream " and do not write temporary file.

Comment: ByteArrayInput/OutputStream. Dunno if Bitmap accepts File or Input/OutputStreams

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I need to declare an empty variable of  byte[] type before using this type of object?

Comment: What's an empty variable? What do you mean? It's an object like any other.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I mean something like: `Byte[] myMemoryFile = null;`

Comment: If you want to use it, you will need to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your data to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and use the byte array of that stream:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); 

// now take the bytes out of your Stream
byte[] imgData = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use an `InputStream` or `OutputStream` you can use `ByteArrayInputStream` or `ByteArrayOutputStream` for in memory handling of the data.

If you have two thread you can also use `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` together to communicate between the threads.